# Redis on spark: variable pipeline in class BinaryJedis cannot be accessed

Tags: scala, apache-spark, redis, spark-streaming

I am trying to write to redis from spark. But I get a compile time error that says "variable pipeline in class BinaryJedis cannot be accessed in redis.clients.jedis.Jedis". My code is  as follows (partially shown):

```
    import org.sedis._
    import redis.clients.jedis._
    ...
    val myRDD = KafkaUtils.createStream(ssc, zkQuorum, group, topic).map(_._2).window(Seconds(300), Seconds(10))
    myRDD.foreachRDD( rdd => {rdd.foreachPartition(it =>{
      val pool = new Pool(new JedisPool(new JedisPoolConfig(), "localhost", 6379, 2000))
      pool.withJedisClient { client => 
        val pipeline = client.pipeline()
        it.foreach {
          case (a,b,c) => pipeline.hmset(a,Map("b" -> b, "c" -> c))
        }
      }

   })})
```

The error I get is as follows:

```
    error: variable pipeline in class BinaryJedis cannot be accessed in redis.clients.jedis.Jedis
    Access to protected variable pipeline not permitted because enclosing object MainExample in package examples is not a subclass of class BinaryJedis in package jedis where target is defined 
    val pipeline = client.pipeline()
```

I have searched for a solution but could not find one.
Can someone help me out?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The issue above is solved. See below

Answer (score 0):

The above issue is solved by removing partitions and replacing Jedis pool with a new instance of jedis for each data tuple written to redis, as shown below. This has worked for me.

```
import org.sedis._
import redis.clients.jedis._
...
val myRDD = KafkaUtils.createStream(ssc, zkQuorum, group, topic)
                      .map(_._2)
                      .window(Seconds(300), Seconds(10))

myRDD.foreachRDD( rdd => {
      rdd.foreach( case(a, b, c) =>{
           val jedis = new Jedis("localhost", 6379)
           val pipeline = jedis.pipelined
           pipeline.hmset(a,Map("b" -> b, "c" -> c))
    })
})
```